# How can I find why my Python program doesn't put me through to the next question?

Tags: python

There is an error in this part of the code:

```
extraAttractions = input("do you want to know about extra attractions, yes or no? ")
if extraAttractions == "yes":
  def attraction():
```

When I ask about extra attractions, even when I type yes as my input, it doesn't put me through to the next question and I'm not sure why.

```
oneAdult = [20.00, 30.00]
oneChild = [12.00, 18.00]
oneSenior = [16.00, 24.00]
familyTicket = [60.00, 90.00]
sixPeoplePlus = [15.00, 22.50]
lionFeeding = 2.50
penguinFeeding = 2.50
eveningBarbeque = 5.00

while True:
  try:
    oneOrTwo = int(input("are you buying tickets for 1 or 2 days? "))
    if oneOrTwo == 1:
      print("day succesfully selected. the prices are, for one adult $", oneAdult[0], "for one child $", oneChild[0], "for one senior $", oneSenior[0], "for a family ticket $",familyTicket[0], "for a group of six people or more(price per ticket) $",sixPeoplePlus[0])
      break;
    elif oneOrTwo == 2:
      print("the prices are, for one adult $", oneAdult[1], "for one child $", oneChild[1], "for one senior $", oneSenior[1], "for a family ticket $",familyTicket[1], "for a group of six people or more(price per ticket) $",sixPeoplePlus[1])
      break;
    else:
      print("your answer needs to be either '1' or '2'")
  except ValueError:
    print("provide this value in integer form")
  continue

extraAttractions = input("do you want to know about extra attractions, yes or no? ")
if extraAttractions == "yes":
  def attraction():
    attractionDay = int(input("Have you booked a ticket for 1 or 2 days"))
    if attractionDay == 1:
      print("The extra attractions are lion feeding for $",lionFeeding,", penguin feeding for $",penguinFeeding,"and the evening barbeque for $",eveningBarbeque)
    elif attractionDay == 2:
      print("The extra attractions are lion feeding for $",lionFeeding,"and penguin feeding for $",penguinFeeding)
    else:
      print("you must input either '1' or '2'")
    
    return attraction()
if extraAttractions == "no":
  print("okay, that's fine")
```

Comment: You don't need the function `attraction()`, so that line can be removed.

Comment: Which line is line 25? And what is the error? Please [edit] your post and cut and paste the message.

Comment: There's a lots of problems in your code, but the main one you're running into, is that if the answer is "yes", you *define* a function, but you don't *run* the function. So, nothing happens. You don't actually need the function, because you're only using that code once. (Also, returning from the function with `return attraction()` makes it recursive, and is very likely an indication that you don't understand how functions are written.)

Comment: you should declare the attraction fn on top then call the function after extrAttraction and do not return anything in the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your error, you define a function, but you don't run it. Fix it like so:

```
extraAttractions = input('... ')
if extraAttractions == "yes":
  def attraction():
    # Code
  attraction()
```

More importantly though, I don't think you understand how functions work. Take a look at [this link](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/function) for help. Your function returns itself, which looks like something that shouldn't happen (thanks to 9769953 for commenting this). It's perfectly fine not to have a return statement for your function, like so:

```
def attraction():
    attractionDay = int(input("Have you booked a ticket for 1 or 2 days"))
    if attractionDay == 1:
      print(f"The extra attractions are lion feeding for {lionFeeding}, penguin feeding for {penguinFeeding}, and the evening barbeque for {eveningBarbeque}")
    elif attractionDay == 2:
      print(f"The extra attractions are lion feeding for {lionFeeding}, and penguin feeding for {penguinFeeding}")
    else:
      print("You must input either '1' or '2'")
```

For tidying up your code, it doesn't look like there's too much to do: most of your code is print statements. If you wanted, you could make a list of everything you print, but I don't recommend doing this. (Example below):

```
list_statements = [
    'thing to print number 1',
    'thing to print number 2',
    'thing to print number {}'
]
print(list_statements[0])
# code
print(list_statements[1])
# code
print(list_statements[2].format('3'))
```

This is just a way to clean up your print statements, you can use `.format()` for the variables as shown. Again, I don't recommend this, since it's messy and hard to edit.

If you want code cleanup, you should consider removing the `def attraction()` function, and just pasting the code into the if block, like so:

```
extraAttractions = input("do you want to know about extra attractions, yes or no? ")
if extraAttractions == "yes":
    attractionDay = int(input("Have you booked a ticket for 1 or 2 days"))
    if attractionDay == 1:
      print("The extra attractions are lion feeding for $",lionFeeding,", penguin feeding for $",penguinFeeding,"and the evening barbeque for $",eveningBarbeque)
    elif attractionDay == 2:
      print("The extra attractions are lion feeding for $",lionFeeding,"and penguin feeding for $",penguinFeeding)
    else:
      print("you must input either '1' or '2'")
```

You could also reformat your `try-except` block, but it'd just make the indentation cleaner, it wouldn't change the code length much.